# Control-Break not working in java using cygwin

Tags: java, thread-dump

I hope this is the right place to ask this, I am running JAVA 7 for Windows 64 bit
. I am using cygwin as the terminal. Every time I try to stop an ongoing program I press control-break, and usually this would send the job to the background but instead I am getting the following Thread Dump.

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode):

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000007504800 nid=0x7c5c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000074ff800 nid=0xd66c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000074f9000 nid=0x5ce8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000074f8000 nid=0x45ec runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000074f7000 nid=0x40a8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x0000000007472000 nid=0xd978 in Object.wait() [0x000000000809e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x0000000788760dc0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
        - locked <0x0000000788760dc0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000007469800 nid=0x6db8 in Object.wait() [0x0000000007d3e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x0000000788760720> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
        - locked <0x0000000788760720> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=6 tid=0x000000000046b800 nid=0x1b68 runnable [0x00000000021ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:242)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        - locked <0x0000000780413290> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
        - locked <0x00000007804153a8> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
        - locked <0x00000007804153a8> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
        at ReadSim.DoJAligner(ReadSim.java:280)
        at ReadSim.getFullSimRead(ReadSim.java:91)
        at ReadSim.main(ReadSim.java:44)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000007460800 nid=0xe610 runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001d4f000 nid=0x7bd4 runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001d51000 nid=0xde18 runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001d52800 nid=0xe1e8 runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001d54000 nid=0x3490 runnable

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001d57800 nid=0x9ab0 runnable

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001d59000 nid=0x2dc0 runnable

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001d5a000 nid=0x9384 runnable

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001d5c800 nid=0x6f58 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000007517800 nid=0x10378 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 124

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 135552K, used 40883K [0x00000007800b0000, 0x000000078b2b0000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 93568K, 4% used [0x00000007800b0000,0x000000078045b9a0,0x0000000785c10000)
  from space 41984K, 88% used [0x0000000788760000,0x000000078aba1298,0x000000078b060000)
  to   space 44352K, 0% used [0x0000000785c10000,0x0000000785c10000,0x0000000788760000)
 PSOldGen        total 262080K, used 65712K [0x0000000680200000, 0x00000006901f0000, 0x00000007800b0000)
  object space 262080K, 25% used [0x0000000680200000,0x000000068422c000,0x00000006901f0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 3452K [0x000000067b000000, 0x000000067c4c0000, 0x0000000680200000)
  object space 21248K, 16% used [0x000000067b000000,0x000000067b35f398,0x000000067c4c0000)
```

Is there something I need to change to make control-break to send the job to the background.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run with `CYGWIN=tty` or use xterm/rxvt then you will get Cygwin Control-Break handling. If you use a standard Cygwin or CMD.EXE shell then you will get Java Control-Break handling.

Comment: The `CYGWIN=tty` option was [removed in February 2012](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2012-02/msg00008.html). This will still work for old Cygwin versions, but everything should work out-of-the-box for recent Cygwin installs.